# How to avoid Maven plugin defined in parent to be overridden by child?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, overriding

The Maven project I'm working on inherits from a parent POM where some project-wide variables are calculated by executing the gmaven-plugin during the validate phase:

**Parent POM:**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5-jenkins-1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals><goal>execute</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
        <source>
          project.properties.put("test.property1", "123");
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now I wanted to use the gmaven-plugin also in a child POM to calculate and set some additional parameters:

**Child POM:**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5-jenkins-1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals><goal>execute</goal></goals>
      <configuration>
        <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
        <source>
          project.properties.put("test.property2", "abc");
        </source>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, this causes the plugin defined in the parent to disappear / to be overwritten. The effective POM contains only the plugin defined in the child and the `test.property1` ends up as `null`.

How can I execute a Maven plugin in the parent *and* another in the child without that they interfere with each other?

Answer (score 2):

```
add : 

    <inherited>true</inherited>

like : 
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5-jenkins-1</version>
     <inherited>true</inherited>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_inherited_Tag_In_Build_Plugins

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/maven-how-to-merging-plugin-configuration-in-complex-projects/#.VhJaH27oBkg) blog entry how to merge configs. This might resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you could just configure another Executions section in child's pom and all references to parent's plugin would disappear.

Comment: It does not work to "just configure another executions section in the child pom". That's in fact the problem. The child overwrites the parent and only `test.property2` becomes available, while `test.property1` is `null`